# Prism RequestNavigate does not work

Tags: wpf, prism

In each view

```
public partial class View2 : UserControl, IRegionMemberLifetime, INavigationAware
{

  public bool KeepAlive
  {
    get { return false; }
  }

  bool INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
  {
    return true;
  }
  void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
  {
    // Intentionally not implemented.
  }
  void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
  {
    this.navigationJournal = navigationContext.NavigationService.Journal;
  }

}
```

Initialize:

```
container.RegisterType<object, View1>("View1");
container.RegisterType<object, View2>("View2");

regionManager.RequestNavigate("Window1", new Uri("View1", UriKind.Relative));
regionManager.RequestNavigate("Window2", new Uri("View2", UriKind.Relative));
```

I am following the developer guide, it does not change the view if view exists.

Comment: Should you not be registering your types against base interfaces rather than against the `object` type?

Comment: in developer guide, it write in this way, i do not know which base interface, does you mean IModule?

Comment: Which developer guide are you referring to?

Comment: Microsft official developer guide

Comment: @Dan Puzey http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2011/03/10/prism-4-region-navigation-with-silverlight-frame-navigation-and-unity.aspx

Comment: In your question i found answer to my question=) Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Are you sure the view gets populated by the container?

I would suggest you to provide a callback for the RequestNavigate method, so you'll be able to track what happens with your view thru the [`NavigationResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.navigationresult_members%28PandP.38%29.aspx):

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate
(
    "Window1",
    new Uri("View2", UriKind.Relative),
    (NavigationResult nr) => 
    {
        var error = nr.Error;
        var result = nr.Result;
        // put a breakpoint here and checkout what NavigationResult contains
    }
);
```

Comment: After 7 years, and I'm thinking let's upvote this answer. Was simple and helped me tackle the issue easily, then I figure I'm the one who answered it...

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/19bcozs/goingfullcircle/

Answer (score 3):

I have seen that if I implement IConfirmNavigateRequest and do not call continutationCallback(true), the navigation fails quietly.

```
public void ConfirmNavigationRequest(NavigationContext navigationContext, Action<bool> continuationCallback)
    {
        //***Should have actual logic here
        continuationCallback(true);
    }
```

While this may not be your case, I figured this out by debugging through the Prism code.  I would suggest you do this to figure out your issue.  Delete the references to the following in each relevant project.

- Microsoft.Practices.Prism
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions

Then add the projects from the PrismLibrary DeskTop, Silverlight or Phone directory (where you installed PRISM).  Then reference these projects.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly my problem, which I justed wasted an hour on.

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
bool INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext) => true;
```

If you want a new view to be created and added to your region each time you call `RequestNavigate()`, `IsNavigationTarget()` must return false instead of true.