# RegionManager.RequestNavigate only gets me System.Object?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I need to add some features to a WPF Project a retired colleague of mine made. Tried to copy the Navigation Features but they won´t work like they should.
I want to open my own XAML File in the Main Window but all I get is System.Object.

Here I register the Views as:

```
        public override void Initialize()
    {


        UnityContainer.RegisterType<RelationView>();
        UnityContainer.RegisterType<RelationNavigationItemView>();


        UnityContainer.RegisterTypeForNavigation<RelationView>();


        RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.NavigationRegion, typeof(RelationNavigationItemView));//this works out fine appears in the Navigation Part

    }
```

The RelationNavigationItemView is simply a button which should open the RelationView in the MainWindow.

Which should happen here as:

```
    private static Uri RelationViewUri = new Uri("/RelationView", UriKind.Relative);
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private DelegateCommand _navigateCommand;

    public RelationNavigationViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public ICommand NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _navigateCommand ?? (_navigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(NavigateCommandExecute, NavigateCommandCanExecute));
        }
    }

    private bool NavigateCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void NavigateCommandExecute()
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, RelationViewUri);  //Here should the new window appears and the ViewModel Constructor should be called but nothing happens, I only get System.Object in the MainContentRegion
    }
```

The Project runs with Prism Version **6.3**.

I hope, someone can help me.

Thanks and Best Regards, Max.

Comment: Could you try to check if your RequestNavigate work as suggested in first answer in [Prism RequestNavigate does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925327/prism-requestnavigate-does-not-work)

Comment: I would also try to remove "/" from Uri, I suppose it can create misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should just navigate to ´"RelationView"`. No need for uri here, it just adds potential for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys it works now. The Constructor was Wrong.

I expected an UnityContainer instead of a IUnityContainer.

Comment: You do not want to inject the container, normally. Your're hiding dependencies, any gain nothing from it.